# How to find out start_url from the website URL in manifest.json

Tags: php, codeigniter, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

```
This origin has one or more service workers, however the page(https://example.ckm) is not scope
```

I'm stuck here, I can't go further than this. Is there an easy way to know what `start_url` is for my dynamic website?
I'm using Codeigniter. Index file or home page are in `application/views/folder/`.

And I place `manifest.jason` in `assets/folder1/folder/`.

So what is the `start_url` for this web page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the `manifest.json` in the project's root or define the
`start_url` like this:

> start_url : "/"

or

> start_url : "../../"

Read this MDN web docs page on [start_url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/start_url).